# how to get item frequency in a row in a r data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like

```
GeneID   person1  person2 ... person100  homo1 homo2 heter homo1count homo2count hetercount
1        AA       AC           AA         AA   CC    AC     25         50        25
2  .....
3  .....
```

How may I get the count 25, 50, 25?

I was trying to use apply as

```
g <- function(df, AA) {
  x = table(df)
  AA = x[which(names(x) == df$homo1)]
  }
x = apply(temp,1,g)
```

But it didn't work, the df$homo1 is always a list

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to get? A vector of the counts in row 1, or the variables with the counts? For the first, `vecCount <- df[1, c("homo1count", "homo2count", "hetercount")]`. For the second, `dfCount <- df[, c("homo1count", "homo2count", "hetercount")]`. Also, please consider only using one assignment operator in your code`<-` or `=`.

Comment: i want to calculate how many AA, CC, AC cumulatively among the 100 persons.

Comment: But the exact string pattern is determined by homo1, homo2, heter, i.e., next row might be CC, GG, CG; row 3 might be AA, TT, AT

Comment: each gene might is select 2 nucleosides form A,C,G,T , different from row to row

Comment: Please include code that allows us to reproduce you problem. The comments here do not reflect what you posted in your original question.

Comment: the data frame is an imported CSV file. I only load the file

Comment: Note that @Neal Fultz's answer includes a toy data.frame that is an attempt to reproduce your problem. When asking questions, it is typically a good idea to provide such an object to give others a chance to work with it.

Comment: I see I see. Thank you so much for your advice. It's a big csv data so i wasn't sure what to do about it XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier if you pivot to long format first, then aggregate. Something like this:

```
require(reshape2)
require(dplyr)

g <- c('AC', 'AA', 'CC')
n <- 30

df <- data.frame(gene_id=1:30, person1=sample(g,n,replace=TRUE),
                               person2=sample(g,n,replace=TRUE),
                               person3=sample(g,n,replace=TRUE),
                               person4=sample(g,n,replace=TRUE),
                               homo1=sample(g,n,replace=TRUE),
                               homo2=sample(g,n,replace=TRUE),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df %>% melt(c("gene_id", "homo1", "homo2")) %>% 
       group_by(gene_id) %>%
       summarise(homo1count=sum(homo1==value),
                 homo2count=sum(homo2==value) ) %>%
       merge(x=df)
```

EDIT: sample output:

```
   gene_id person1 person2 person3 person4 homo1 homo2 homo1count homo2count
1        1      AA      CC      AC      AA    AC    CC          1          1
2        2      AC      AA      CC      CC    CC    AA          2          1
3        3      AC      CC      CC      AA    CC    AA          2          1
4        4      AC      AC      AC      AA    AA    AA          1          1
5        5      CC      AC      AA      AC    AA    AC          1          2
6        6      CC      AC      CC      CC    AA    AA          0          0
7        7      AA      AA      AC      AA    CC    CC          0          0
8        8      AA      AC      AA      CC    AC    CC          1          1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My problem is that homo1 is different each row.

Comment: homo1 is different in each row of my answer. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: the homo1count is the count of  "XX" appeared at homo1 colume at that specific row

Comment: That's what this answer produces.

Comment: The previous comment was written before your first comment shows up. Somehow there was a time lag. I've been reading the code and tried it since your comment. Thanks very much for your help! I don't know much about %>% so didn't respond immediately. Sorry about that.

Comment: I was trying to search “%>%”+ r in google but didnt have much luck. Could you kindly let me know what is this thing called? I guess it is transmitting intermediate values during the operation? 
     And also, is the last match function same as https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html? How come I can directly use x = df? (I am only asking because i don't know how to assign the output to my variables...the result matrix is printed correctly but my original data frame is unchanged.)

Comment: Still haven't found a way to get the data out... Tried to break the chain and do it step by step, with

Comment: melted <- melt(df,c("rs.", "homoRef", "homoOther","heter")) 
grouped <- group_by(melted, homoRef,homoOther,heter) ;
homo1 <- summarise(grouped,homo1count = sum(homoRef == value)) ; 
homo2 <- summarise(grouped,homo2count = sum(homoOther == value)) ; 
hetero <- summarise(grouped,hetercoun t = sum(heter == value))
merge(homo1 = df)

Comment: and my summarise output only has 12 rows, when merging the error always happen

Comment: finally knew how to do it, three summarise sentense could be combined into one, and  last sense should be merge(hetero, x = df) XD. Sorry for the buzz. Thanks for your help!